# Hard to understand GCC assembly instructions to calculate conditional jump

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I have the following code:

```
if(( a<0 ) || ( a>global_count ))  //global_count is a global int
{
    print error;
}

normal_flow
    ...
```

Now here's the assembler that GCC generates:

```
cmpl 0x0 , 0x10(%ebp) //first check
js print_error
mov 0x8(%ebp) , %eax
mov 0x8(%eax) , %eax 
cmp 0x10(%ebp) , %eax //second check
jge normal_flow
print_error
```

I don't understand why the `jge`? I see it's using `mov`, instead of `movl`, but I believe it should be `jle` in this case or `jg` if we change jump target... or am I thinking wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `jge` because the compiler swapped both the operands and the condition. It's doing `global_count >= a`. Notice that `0x10(%ebp)` is `a` and `%eax` is `global_count`. To complicate matters further, at&t syntax itself has operands reversed.

Comment: Sure, but from what I understand its: `cmp src, dest` if src (a) is greater than or equal to dest (global_count), then jump, right? That's what I understand from the first comparison at least.

Comment: Wrong. The sense of the comparison is `dest op src`. Even in the first case, it's doing `if (a - 0 < 0)` (`cmp` is a `sub` in disguise).